# Is heaven sentient being like hell?

Tags: jannah, jahannam

In Islamic youtube videos I learned that Hell is sentient being. It mentioned that the hell is being dragged by 70k (I think) angels and which it will take 3 types of evil people before judgments day. While also many hadith hell asking Allah if there are more people. So, I wonder if heaven is also sentient being? Is there any where in hadith or Quran where it mentions being sentient or its talking to Allah confirming it to be sentient?

Comment: What makes you think that hell is sentient in the first place? Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @SpiderRico I have mentioned that in my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'sentient being' however based on the fact that you mentioned that hell talks. This would be my answer in regards to Paradise as that also talks. Whether that makes them a 'sentient being' or not, Allah knows best.

Likewise, Paradise requests for people to enter it when they ask Allah for Paradise three times and hell talks asking Allah to save the person from it when they seek refuge in Allah against it. This summarizes these hadith.

Anas bin Malik (RA) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said: 'Whoever asks Allah for Paradise three times, Paradise says: 'O Allah, admit him into Paradise', and whoever seeks refuge from the Fire says: 'O Allah, save him from the Fire.' (Jami' at - Tirmidhi, Book 38, Hadith 2772)

And Allah knows best

Comment: Salaam ... I'm not sure how this answers the question asked above.

Comment: Wa alaikum as salaam. I have edited it and answered it based on the question asked now. JzK

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing 'sentient' about heaven in the Quran but there are some Hadiths where it is the case. E.g:

The Hell and the Paradise fell into dispute and the Hell said: I have been dis- tinguished by the proud and the haughty. **And the Paradise said: What is the matter with me that the meek and the humble amongst people and the downtrodden and the simple enter me? Thereupon Allah said to the Paradise: You are (the means) of My Mercy whereby I show mercy to those of My servants whom 1 wish**, and He said to the Hell: You are (the means) of punishment whereby 1 punish those of My servants whoml wish. Both of you will be full. The Hell will riot be filled up until **Allah puts down His (left) foot into hellfire**. The Hell would say: Enough, enough, enough, and at that time it will be filled up, all its parts integrated together. [Reference](https://sunnah.com/muslim/53/42)

Comment: [50:30](https://quran.com/50/30?translations=20)

Comment: @UmH Edited....